# How do I search a book list class by the author's last name but with multiple authors?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, programming-languages

So I finished my project, but my only problem is that I can only search one author at a time. I seem to not be able to figure it out.

This is what I have..am I missing something thats not making me able to find more than one author's last name?

```
void BookRecordUI::FindBookLast()   //allows us to search a book by the last name of the author from the book record...
{       
    string Last;

    cout << "Enter Book by Last Name of Author: " << endl;
    getline(cin, Last);
    Collection.FindBookAuthorLast(Last);
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

EDIT: So basically I want to find multiple authors..for example, if I inputted John Hopkins and Wilson Greene, I want to pull both authors last name at the same time. Sorry for not clearly explaining it.

I also have this part as well..

```
void BookRecordList::FindBookAuthorLast(string Last)
{
    int K;
    for(K = 0; K < (int)List.size(); K++)
        if(List[K].GetAuthorLast() == Last)
        cout << List[K].GetTitle() << " " << List[K].GetAuthorFirst() << " " << List[K].GetAuthorLast() << " " << List[K].GetPublisher() << " " << List[K].GetPublisherAddress() << " " << List[K].GetPublisherPhone() << "  "
             << List[K].GetPublisherContact() << " "<< List[K].GetCategory() << "  " << List[K].GetDate() << endl;
};
```

My whole program is really long, so I dont want to overwhelm you guys by posting the whole thing up..

Comment: How do you handle multiple authors in other places?

Comment: Your question id a bit strange and my answer would be - `implement it`

Comment: This is way too little information to allow us to help you.  I don't know what a `Collection` is, or how it's laid out.  Also, what do you mean by searching only one author at a time?  Do you want to, say, find books by Asimov and Clarke, or do you want to include Harbison & Steele's book when searching on Steele?

Comment: Please format your code by selecting it, then pushing the `{ }` button.

Comment: if this is homework it should be tagged as such ... there are many ways to implement this. If you are looking for a code snippet without a question I'd suggest google.

Answer (score 0):

You do not give us a lot of informations about what is a "book" and what is a `Collection`.
But, it seems that you already implement a function that returns you the expected result for one string (the last name of an author).

What you can do is use multiples times your function `FindBookAuthorLast` with a different last name each time.

Or, implement a function that takes a vector of string in parameters and that returns you a vector of Book (or whatever is your class containing the books).

EDIT :

With the new informations you posted, here is  a way to do it :

(This is not the only solution to do it, there is a lot)

(Code not compiled, not tested)

```
void BookRecordList::FindBookAuthorLast(vector<string> Last)
{
  int K;
  vector<string>::iterator author_it = Last.begin();
  for ( ; author_it != Last.end(); ++author_it)
  {
      for(K = 0; K < (int)List.size(); K++)
         if(List[K].GetAuthorLast() == *author_it)
         cout << List[K].GetTitle() << " " << List[K].GetAuthorFirst() << " " << List[K].GetAuthorLast() << " " <<    List[K].GetPublisher() << " " << List[K].GetPublisherAddress() << " " << List[K].GetPublisherPhone() << "  "
           << List[K].GetPublisherContact() << " "<< List[K].GetCategory() << "  " << List[K].GetDate() << endl;
  }
};
```

To build the `vector<string>` to give to the function `FindBookAuthorLast`, iterate on getline().

Comment: I keep getting an error on "Iterator" and "FindBookAuthorLast"

Comment: 1) I made a typo, it is not "Iterator" but "iterator" (no uppercase)
2) This code does not suffice to itself. You have to work around it.

Comment: You are welcome. If you need more help, do not hesitate to add comment to my answer in order to poke me.

Answer (score 0):

You *may* need to change your `Book` definition to enable searching for multiple authors:

```
struct Author
{
  std::string& get_name() const;
};

struct Book
{
  std::vector<Author> m_authors; // A book can have 1 or more authors
  bool has_author(std::string author_name) const
  {
    std::vector<Author>::const_iterator iter;
    for (iter = m_authors.begin();
         iter != m_authors.end();
         ++iter)
    {
       if (iter.get_name() == author_name)
       {
         return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
};
```

The objective now is to write a *predicate* or functor that will call `Book::has_author`.

This is one solution to your issue, there are probably others when you give it more thought.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe all you want is to loop over your function:

```
void BookRecordUI::FindBookLast()   //allows us to search a book by the last name of the author from the book record...
{       
    string Last;

    do { 
        cout << "Enter Book by Last Name of Author: " << endl;
        getline(cin, Last);
        Collection.FindBookAuthorLast(Last);
    }
    while(!Last.empty());
}
```

(not tested).